# Send only specific value to server in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, templates

I have a html code like this:

```
{% for i, j, k in full_name %}
    {{ i }} {{ j }} 
    <input type="text" name="follow_id" value="{{ k }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Follow"><br /> <br />   

{% endfor %}
```

The output looks like this:

```
user1 user_id_of_user1 follow_button

user2 user_id_of_user2 follow_button

user3 user_id_of_user3 follow_button
```

If I press the follow button of user3 I want to send the id of user3 only so that I can access it in server like this:

```
followed_user = request.POST['follow_id'] 
# Process
```

But, no matter which follow_button I press, I get the user id of only user1. How to fix this?

Comment: you might try wrapping each section in its own `<form>` tag within the loop.

Comment: Let's say 10000 users, so I should write 10000 forms and ten thousand views(functions) to handle each id?

Comment: if you had 10k users, i would dynamically create everything in javascript so you'd only have to transfer the data.  but tbh, i'm still a little unclear on what your doing.  it would help to see the generated html that you have now for 3 or so users, including the surrounding `<form>` tag or tags

Comment: I am trying to help you.  I'm telling you that I'm still not clear about the question, so seeing additional code would help

Comment: Your code is wrong. You'd need your names to be under the form __folow_id[]__ so the POST data contains an array of all the inputs. In your case, only the first, or last (I don't know) input of each name is forwarded to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Django issue, but a HTML issue. Here is the work around: 1 form for each user:

```
{% for i, j, k in full_name %}
    <form action="mydomain.com/mysubmiturl/" method="POST"><!-- Leave action empty to submit to this very same html -->
        {% csrf_token %} <!-- Django server only accept POST requests with a CSRF token -->
        {{ i }} {{ j }} 
        <input type="text" name="follow_id" value="{{ k }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Follow"><br /> <br />
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that all the forms submit to the **same URL**, and thus the **same view function** !

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents, I would use some jQuery for this job.

In your template:

```
{% for i, j, k in full_name %}
    {{ i }} {{ j }} 
    <a href="#" id="js-follow-{{ k }}" class="follow-button">Follow</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then submit the data using AJAX:

```
$('.follow-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('js-follow-', '');    

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'path/to/view',
        data: {'follow_id': this_id},
        success: function (resp) {
            // do something with response here?    
        }
    });
});
```